# Trouble with multiple autofs mounts

Tags: autofs

So, I am trying to mount folders from server1 and server2 on server0. I can't seem to get the second folder mounted. Here is what I did:

1. Created a folders /nfs/home and /nfs/programs on server0 . I want all the user directories of server1 mounted at /nfs/home. I want all the programs on server2 mounted at /nfs/programs (on server2 they are at /home/programs).
2. Edited auto.master to have these entries:

   ```
   /nfs/home                                   /etc/auto.home --ghost
   /nfs/programs                               /etc/auto.programs --ghost
   ```
3. The corresponding auto.* files are:

   ```
   * 10.0.0.34:/home/&
   ```

   and

   ```
   * 10.0.7.10:/home/programs/&
   ```

I have enabled the nfs service and added:

```
    / server*.domain(rw)
```

to my /etc/exports file.

I disabled firewalld ( this is an internal network ).

The home folders mount fine to /nfs/home/* but there is nothing for /nfs/programs when I try to cd into them. I'm I making some simple mistake that I can't see?

**--Update!--**

It looks like my exports file on server2 has a problem. I changed it from:

```
    / server*.domain(rw)
```

to:

```
    /home server*.domain(rw)
```

since I'm (for now) only interested in mounting from /home/programs. It seems to be working now. It seems you cannot share the root directory with nfs? Here is my df:

```
[root@server programs]# df
Filesystem                     1K-blocks       Used Available Use%         Mounted on
/dev/mapper/centos-root         52403200    5145132  47258068  10% /
devtmpfs                         8055632          0   8055632   0% /dev
tmpfs                            8071364        256   8071108   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                            8071364       9444   8061920   1% /run
tmpfs                            8071364          0   8071364   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/nvme0n1p1                    508588     161660    346928  32% /boot
/dev/mapper/centos-home        188766152      81816 188684336   1% /home
tmpfs                            1614276         20   1614256   1% /run/user/1000
tmpfs                            1614276         24   1614252   1% /run/user/42
tmpfs                            1614276          8   1614268   1% /run/user/0
tmpfs                            1614276          0   1614276   0% /run/user/1015
10.0.0.34:/home/me            1170949120 1135836160  35112960  98% /nfs/home/zdhughes
10.0.7.10:/home/programs/root6.06  182973440   11874304 171099136   7% /nfs/programs/root6.06
```

Can anyone provide some nuance about what is going on here? How would one make the whole disk mountable?

Thanks!

Comment: Two quick questions: 1) what variant is this (*bsd, Linux of some stripe)? and 2) you noted starting nfs services, did you also start autofs services?

Comment: can you mount that `/nfs/programs` manually ?

Comment: are you able to mount the `programs` share from server2 onto server0 with a hard nfs mount command ? Like `mount -t nfs 10.0.7.10:/home/programs /nfs/programs` ??

Comment: @ThomasN I am using CentOS 7, yes autofs is running.

Comment: @MelBurslan When I use  mount -t nfs 10.0.7.10:/home/programs /nfs/programs I get: mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting 10.0.7.10:/home/programs

Comment: probably somthing is not right art server2's NFS configuration or it is using a different NFS version which is incompatible with the NFS client version of server0, It is hard to determine without actually testing commands on the system.

Comment: Only thing I can think of is that when you were mounting both root filesystems, you were running into issues with files and directories having that same inode numbers on your client. Total guess, but I don't have much else to go on.